# Facebook-Page-Scraper Not Scarping Multiple Pages

Tags: python, facebook, web-scraping

I'm using facebook-page-scraper to pull Facebook posts. I have a list of about 90 different facebook pages I need to scrape from, when it iterates through the loop I can see the variable name change but it only scrapes the first page. Is there some type of connection or HTTP client I need to close?

```
sample_lst = ['BigBendNPS','YosemiteNPS', 'RockyNPS']

def scrap_facebook(page_nm):
    page_name = page_nm
    posts_count = 1000
    browser = "chrome"
    timeout = 600 #600 seconds
    headless = True
    park_scrap = facebook_page_scraper.Facebook_scraper(page_name, 
                                                        posts_count, 
                                                        browser, 
                                                        timeout=timeout, 
                                                        headless=headless)
    csv_data = park_scrap.scrap_to_csv(PATH+page_nm)

for p in sample_lst:
    print(f'Scraping Facebook Page Name: {p}')
    scrap_facebook(p)
```